# Check if control present in main Ul tag or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following structure.

```
<ul id="main">
    <li id="a"/>
    <ul id="main1">
        <li id="b"/>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

In above code when the user clicked on the button, I want to check whether `li` with `id=b` present in `id=main ul` or not using **jquery**. So pleases let me know how can I check using **jquery**.

Comment: Which button do you mean?

Comment: <ul id="main">
    <li id="a"></li>
    <ul id="main1">
        <li id="b"></li>
    </ul>
</ul> actual code will be this you did'nt close li tag

Answer (score 1):

Try this for a check:

```
if($('#main').has('li[id="b"]').length > 0)
```

This will check, if main has any li element with id equals b. The result is an array with all elements or zero elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code to achieve what you want

```
if ($("ul[id='main']").find("li[id='b']").length > 0) 
{
     // Element is present.
}
else 
{
     // Element is not present.
}
```